# Can't scroll back after cat with mosh, tmux and iterm2 setup

Tags: macos, ubuntu, tmux, scrolling, iterm2

My setup is the following: https://filippo.io/my-remote-shell-session-setup

When I do `apt-get update` on my server I can see all the output and am also able to scroll back as I expect. When I do `cat package.json` I just can see the content fitting on my current terminal size and scrolling back does not work as expected. I end up somewhere in the middle of the output from the command before.

Is there a difference in the output of these two? And any idea how I can get scrolling back also to work with `cat`? I'm using OSX as my local machine and connect to an Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference between the output those two commands.

It's hard to say exactly what the issue is, but one thing you can try is using a pager to manually scroll through the contents of a file:

```
less package.json
```